# How do I add a link to a similar product in the short discription of another product

Tags: link

I am trying to add a link to a similar product in the short discription of another product.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the wysiwyh editor enabled. On Content / Short Description, press **Insert Widget**, select **Widget Type**: "Catalog product Link", select **Template**: "Product Link Inline" and finaly on **Product** select the desired product. Depending on the theme, you may have additional options on Widget Type.